# Barchart formatting in JSON/Column formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, chart, column-formatting

I am working on JSON/column formatting. I want to show column data in barchart format.

(e.g. In below image `Progress` is the column name and 100/75/50/25 are four different items.)

I know we can create progress bar. But I do not know if it is possible to show data in bar chart format. If yes, then please suggest me on this.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to create a horizontal bar? As given in example at: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-simple-data-visualizations. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I am little bit unclear here. Are you trying to render single column value in a graph as shown above in screenshot, or there are multiple columns which you want to place is this graph. Also, can you use predefine icons/images like shown in above screenshot?

Comment: @ThinkB4Code I am trying to render single column in a grapgh. And bars of this graph will be filled based on the column value (25/50/75/100). The image in my question is cropped from one of the document. I am new to JSON scripting so I am not sure if I can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou for clarifications. I created a simple solution for column formatting. You can improve in CSS part, while I am using old school CSS to render the bar graphs. Below example have four bars, each representing 25% completion.

Use the below link to see code on Github Gist.
https://gist.github.com/thinkb4code/0e11bb6c3a00555484260905a0d1198a

There are two files in it.

1. **bar-graph.html**
   This is the basic HTML I used to render bar graph. For me column formatting start with basic HTML concept. First identify the design and then convert it to JSON schema.
2. **bar.graph.json**
   This is the actual JSON schema we need to put as column formatting.

Here is the [reference video for you](https://www.thinkb4code.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Bar-Graph-Using-Column-Formatting.mp4), how this looks.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and will let know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution really helped me :)

Comment: You are welcome, sharing is caring :)